# What do you call it when the current generation thinks the previous is better/more poetic?

Tags: vocabulary

It's referred to as the "allure of nostalgia" in the wiki entry for Midnight in Paris.

Comment: I'd call it normal.

Comment: What about 'nostalgia'?

Comment: What do you mean by more poetic !!! Nostalgia is yearning to get back to be past , it does not necessarily means that the person thinks the previous is better !!

Comment: Nostalgia's not what it used to be.

Comment: I'm confident when I say my children feel no nostalgia for the era before cable television and Nintendo. Doesn't nostalgia require some recollection of the era in question?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - the character in *Midnight in Paris* was very familiar with the Paris of Stein and Hemingway, as well of that of Toulouse-Lautrec; he wanted to "return" to the former.

Comment: @medica I understand that. But, "current generation thinks the previous" would imply the reverse.

Answer (score 8):

It is also referred to as the **Golden Age fallacy** in Midnight in Paris.

It's a mixture of romanticisation of the past, and minor negationism; ignoring the negatives and focusing only on the positives.

It's closely related to "the grass is always greener".

Answer (score 4):

There is a commonplace longing for **the good old days**.

For example, there is often a longing for the turn-of-the-century era (1900 not 2000) that is thought to be kinder and gentler than the later 20th century, as exemplified in Hollywood sagas like *Meet me in St. Louis*. A reading of some authors, like Stephen Crane's [*Maggie, Girl of the Streets*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggie%3a_A_Girl_of_the_Streets), paints a much more realistic and somewhat brutal picture of that period.

As [Ms. Simon](http://www.metrolyrics.com/anticipation-lyrics-carly-simon.html) points out, anticipation of what is to come may be ill-advised, since *these are the good old days*.

Answer (score 2):

How about "[nostalgic romanticization](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=VZpbAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=%22nostalgic+romanticization%22&source=bl&ots=SQNumupHLL&sig=6Kv2PQT-rBYrU3HbkYJZbYWbJeQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=0v9IU4S5LaHW0QWtnIFo&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22nostalgic%20romanticization%22&f=false)" and "[nostalgic romanticism](http://segonku.unl.edu/~jheppler/showindian/analysis/cody-indians/)?"

Answer (score 1):

Saudade:  *It describes a deep emotional state of nostalgic or profound melancholic longing for an absent something or someone that one loves. Moreover, it often carries a repressed knowledge that the object of longing may never return.[2] A stronger form of saudade may be felt towards people and things whose whereabouts are unknown, such as a lost lover, or a family member who has gone missing.
Saudade was once described as "the love that remains"*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade

Answer (score 0):

I think you could easily say that they are **reminiscing** and being **sentimental**.

Freud, with deep introspection, would gather that there is a **delusion of history**. He is right.

I for one like the term:

> **romanticizing**:  deal with or describe in an idealized or unrealistic fashion; make (something) seem better or more appealing
>   than it really is.